# Do the following modifications to the 2019 UA artificer make it unbalanced with other classes?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, homebrew-review, artificer

From what I could tell, the [2019 UA Artificer](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA-Artificer-2019.pdf) lacked the cool factor in various areas and it was rather limited when it came to crafting, so I made the following modifications.

Am I missing anything that could result in this becoming much more powerful compared to other classes, rather than just increasing the artificer's damage output a bit and increasing the versatility when it comes to crafting? Is this modified artificer unbalanced?

---

Only the changed features are noted below:

> #### Tool Expertise
>
> Starting at 3rd level, your proficiency bonus is doubled for any
>   ability check you make that uses your proficiency with a tool. You can
>   craft anything for which you have the required tool proficiency in the
>   quarter of time required for half of the price.
>
> #### Arcane Armament
>
> Starting at 5th level, you can use a cantrip as a bonus action,
>   whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.
>
> ### Alchemist
>
> #### Homunculus
>
> > Ability Scores
> >
> > Str 4
> >
> > Dex 10
> >
> > Con 11
> >
> > Int 10
> >
> > Wis 10
> >
> > Cha 7
>
> At levels 4, 8, 12, 16, and 20, the homunculus gains +2 to its
>   Dexterity score.
>
> ***Acidic Spittle.*** *Ranged Weapon Attack:* +2 to hit, range 30 ft., one
>   target you can see. *Hit:* 1d6 + Dex acid damage. At levels 5, 11, and 17,
>   the damage increases by 1d6.
>
> ***Buoyancy.*** The target gains a flying speed of 10 feet for 10 minutes.
>   The speed gained is increased by 10 more feet at levels 5, 11, and 17.
>
> ***Resilience.*** The target gains a number of temporary hit points equal to
>   2d6 + your Intelligence modifier. At levels 5, 11, and 17, the temporary hit
>   points gained increase by 2d6.
>
> ### Artillerist
>
> #### Arcane Turret
>
> - **Flamethrower**: The turret exhales fire in an adjacent 15-foot cone that
>     you designate. Each creature in that area must make a Dexterity saving
>     throw against your spell save DC, taking 1d8 fire damage on a failed
>     save or half as much damage on a successful one. The fire ignites any
>     flammable objects in the area that aren’t being worn or carried. At
>     level 5,11,17 the fire damage increases by 1d8
> - **Force Ballista**: Make a ranged spell attack, originating from the
>     turret, at one creature or object within 120 feet of it. On a hit, the
>     target takes 1d8 force damage, and if the target is a creature, it is
>     pushed up to 5 feet away from the turret. At level 5,11,17 the damage
>     increases by 1d8 and the push effect is increased by five feet.
> - **Defender**: The turret emits a burst of positive energy that grants
>     itself and each creature of your choice within 10 feet of it a number
>     of temporary hit points equal to 1d8 + your Intelligence modifier
>     (minimum of +1). At level 5,11,17 the temporary hitpoints granted
>     increase by 1d8.

Comment: For sections where only some of the text is changed (like the individual Arcane Turret options), can you use italics to indicate which portion are UNchanged from the original? It's good that you're only including the changed features, but for those that haven't changed entirely it would help with answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being able to attack and cast a cantrip is significantly better than just getting an extra attack, since cantrips scale. This could get out of hand for multiclass characters, who could use it to essentially stack extra attacks. For example a Fighter/Artificer could make two attacks, then cast Green Flame Blade for another, even more powerful attack.

To keep the flavor, I would suggest changing this to be that you can make an attack as a bonus action after casting a cantrip, and require it to be with a magic weapon, as per the original.